# C# deploy, problems with folders

Tags: c#

I've finished my app and used the visual studio installer to create a package with all the files that aplication need.

But the problem is that, if the user install the program in ProgramFiles directory, it won't start because he needs admin Rigths (This because the program needs sqlServerCe).

How i can avoid this situation?

Another question, if the program has the sqlServer and sqlServerCe in prerequesites it needs the sqlServerCe.dll?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe it is because you need an application manifest. You can specify privilege information this way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I needes to ask for admin rigths in my application

Comment: Please consider adding this answer (and the other one) as a comment on foobar1234's answer, then deleting this answer.